# How to access local ip in an external network

Tags: networking, stream, ip, ip-address

I have a html page where I need to show a mjpeg stream. The camera has a local IP, in the same network with the backend server (which I know the IP and have privileges). How do I reach the local camera IP using the server IP to show it in the html page?

Comment: Is the camera wired to internet? Otherwise are you connected to the same network?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same network with the backend server. I'm able to access the câmera using a double ssh connection (access the server with public ip and then access the câmera using local ip).

Comment: But what I need is to send a http request to the câmera.

Comment: have you tried entering the camera's `ip:port` in your browser url?

Comment: This does not works because my pc is not under the same network.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no generic way to do this code-wise. It depends on your camera's model. Usually, you would need to embed your camera's plug-in code into your page. I advise you to consult your camera's manual instructions or reach out to the manufacturer for assistance.
Check out this link (it only applies to that specific camera model): https://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Embedding-IP-Camera-Web-Page-s/326.htm